# subprocess stdout readline hang for special command call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a binary which will stub there to wait external trigger:

```
# ./a2dp_sink_demo
Packet Log: /tmp/hci_dump.pklg
No audio playback.
Audio will be stored to 'av2dp_sink_demo.wav' file.
Starting BTstack ...
```

I use next python script to call it, and get the output of this binary, and I confirm the log goes to stdout, not stderr with `./a2dp_sink_demo > log.txt`:

**test.py:**

```
import subprocess

# demo_full_path = "ping -c 4 127.0.0.1"
demo_full_path = "./a2dp_sink_demo"
proc = subprocess.Popen(demo_full_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, bufsize=0)
while proc.poll() is None:
    print("start")
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print("output is %s " % line)
proc.kill()
```

Next is the running log, it justs hang at `readline`, never continue. Additional, if use `ps aux | grep a2dp` to check, the subprocess is running:

```
# python test.py
start
```

**Question: why `proc.stdout.readline()` can't get log of that binary?**

**But**, if I comment `demo_full_path = "./a2dp_sink_demo"` and uncomment `demo_full_path = "ping 127.0.0.1"`, it will runs as next:

```
start
output is b'PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.\n'
start
output is b'64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms\n'
start
output is b'64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms\n'
start
output is b'64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms\n'
start
output is b'64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms\n'
start
output is b'\n'
start
output is b'--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---\n'
start
output is b'4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 76ms\n'
```

**What's strange here?**

You could see with the same code: call subprocess `ping` is ok, but `a2dp_sink_demo` not ok.

The `a2dp_sink_demo` comes from an open source project, [source here](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/a2dp_sink_demo.c)

**How to reproduce?**

To give you an environment which could reproduce my problem, I create a docker image on docker hub including the binary `a2dp_sink_demo`, you could use next to reproduce my issue:

```
$ docker run --rm -it atline/abc:1 /bin/bash
root@8c7a267930d3:/tmp# python --version
Python 3.9.1
root@8c7a267930d3:/tmp# ls
a2dp_sink_demo  test.py
root@8c7a267930d3:/tmp# python test.py
start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any special thoughts for what will be the possible reason & potential fix in python code? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try: `proc = subprocess.Popen(demo_full_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, text=True); stdout, _ = proc.communicate(); print(stdout, end='')`

Comment: `a2dp_sink_demo` - is it running or is it working? The two are not exactly the same, like depending on a flag https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/a2dp_sink_demo.c#L1107 may attempt to do something with the stdin, and it may simply hang on having `None`. What happens if you put a `printf()` at the beginning of that callback(?)-main? What happens if you look up the "real" `main()` and print something there? What happens if you provide stdin?

Comment: @Booboo It just hangs, as `a2dp_sink_demo` won't exit, so I guess `communicate` which wait for process exit not a good option here?

Comment: You were already hanging with the code you were running, so this was no worse. I had suggested `communicate` only because it is generally considered the recommended way of running `Popen` and if for some reason there was something subtle going on I thought it might be worth a try. Any reason why you specify *shell=True* (without that you *do* need to pass a list of strings as the command)?

Comment: @tevemadar In fact, I'm not familar with its sourcecode, just I get a binary. YES, I tried it just now, if I type something after `./a2dp_sink_demo` print `Starting BTstack ...`, I could see it really expect stdin here, as it response to my input. But, you see, even I did not type anything, I could get the output with `Starting BTstack ...`, how can I get this(`Starting BTstack`) with python subprocess program without input anything?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your last comment. If you specify on `Popen` `sysin=subprocess.PIPE` and use `stdout, _ = communicate()` that should be like passing an immediate end-of-file on sysin. Or you can specify `communicate(input="some string")`

Comment: @Booboo, I mean with any method above, I can't get `Starting BTstack ...` output. The `Starting BTstack ...` is something output when I separtely run the command `./a2dp_sink_demo` in bash without using python. Meanwhile, `a2dp_sink_semo` is something never exit, so `communicate` which wait for subprocess exit won't be an option, I have to loop to get the realtime output, not wait a process exit, then get the whole output.

Comment: BTW, if you have `docker` installed, `docker run --rm -it atline/abc:1 /bin/bash` is the command which can completely reproduce my environment. I also installed vim in that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer for myself: it looks the output of this binary is fully buffered. So change the output to line buffered with `stdbuf` made me fix this issue:

> **NAME**
>
> stdbuf - Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.
>
> ```
> -o, --output=MODE
>     adjust standard output stream buffering
> ```
>
> If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered.

**test.py:**

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal

demo_full_path = "stdbuf -oL ./a2dp_sink_demo"
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    demo_full_path,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
    preexec_fn=os.setsid,
)
while proc.poll() is None:
    line = proc.stdout.readline().decode()
    print("output is: %s " % line)
    if line.find("Starting BTstack") >= 0:
        break

os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

**Execution:**

```
root@cdd1898ee06a:/tmp# python3 test.py
output is: Packet Log: /tmp/hci_dump.pklg

output is: No audio playback.
 tcsetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device
tcsetattr ICANON: Inappropriate ioctl for device

output is: Audio will be stored to 'av2dp_sink_demo.wav' file.

output is: Starting BTstack ...
```